# R Create column that provides grouping number for each distinct group

Tags: r

I need to add a column to my data that contains a number grouping for each distinct combination of other columns.  It will likely be more clear with this example:

```
# Make data
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5),
y = c(2, 2,3,4,5,1,3,4,5,1),
value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
# Print the data
df
   x y value
1  1 2     1
2  1 2     2
3  2 3     3
4  3 4     4
5  4 5     5
6  5 1     6
7  2 3     7
8  3 4     8
9  4 5     9
10 5 1    10
```

I need to add a "Location" column that has the numbers each unique (or distinct) combination of x and y.  Duplicated x and y combinations should all use the same number.  In my example there are 5 unique combinations of x and y, so I only have a maximum of 5 Locations.  My goal output is this:

```
   x y value Location
1  1 2     1        1
2  1 2     2        1
3  2 3     3        2
4  3 4     4        3
5  4 5     5        4
6  5 1     6        5
7  2 3     7        2
8  3 4     8        3
9  4 5     9        4
10 5 1    10        5
```

I imagine doing something like this:

```
   df <- df %>% 
    group_by(x,y) %>% 
    mutate(Location = ndistinct(x,y)
```

But this doesn't work. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df %>%  mutate(., Location=group_indices(., x,y))
   x y value Location
1  1 2     1        1
2  1 2     2        1
3  2 3     3        2
4  3 4     4        3
5  4 5     5        4
6  5 1     6        5
7  2 3     7        2
8  3 4     8        3
9  4 5     9        4
10 5 1    10        5
```

See [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_indices.html) and [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2160).

Not quite as straightforward as I thought to start with.

*Update*

To answer OP's question: the dot `.` is a placeholder for "the object on the left hand side of the pipe" (`%>%`).  Normally you don't need it because, by default, magrittr (the package which defines the pipe) assumes that you want to use the object on the left hand side of the pipe as the *first* argument to the function on the right hand side of the pipe, and makes the substitution for you.   This is very helpful because the tidyverse is designed so that the object on the left hand side of the pipe is always the first argument to the function on the right hand side - so you don't have to use the dot.

If you use functions that don't belong to the tidyverse, you sometimes need the dot to override magrittr's default behaviour.

I wrote my first version of this answer without testing the code because the solution seemed "obvious".  But I did test it afterwards (at the same time as OP reported the error) and found that it didn't work.  A quick Google brought me to the github issue  in the second link above, and hence to the correct answer.

I don't yet understand why, in this particular case, a tidyverse function doesn't work as I expect. (Other than taking the easy way out and saying that my expectation was wrong!)

Comment: I tried that solution as well, but I get this error:Error in UseMethod("group_indices_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_indices_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: Yep.  Fixed. Apologies.

Comment: Thanks!  What does the "." do?  Or how did you know that's what it needed?

Answer (score 1):

In base R we can use:

```
df$location <- as.numeric(factor(paste(df$x,df$y)))


   x y value location
1  1 2     1        1
2  1 2     2        1
3  2 3     3        2
4  3 4     4        3
5  4 5     5        4
6  5 1     6        5
7  2 3     7        2
8  3 4     8        3
9  4 5     9        4
10 5 1    10        5
```